# Spring boot cannot resolve view page issue in mustache

Tags: spring, spring-boot

```
package springboot.web;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

```
index.html




<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>start</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>start</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

```
build.gradle


buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.9.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group 'com.jojoldu.book'
version '1.0.4-SNAPSHOT-'+new Date().format("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
sourceCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mustache')
    compile('com.h2database:h2')

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client')
    compile('org.springframework.session:spring-session-jdbc')

    compile("org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client")

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
}
```

[image]

I am using intellij and spring boot and use mustache to use templates. I installed mustache plugin and changed to .mustache instead of .html, but a can not resolve Mvc view error occurs in the controller and a 404 error occurs when I run it. What is the cause?  ?

I put the same html file in the static folder and tried to /index.html in the view resolver but couldn't find it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The name of the file in `src/main/resources/templates` must be `index.mustache` instead of `index.html`. This is the default for Spring BOot when auto configuring mustache.

Comment: I tried that too but it didn't work I added the image above

Comment: That only shows the rename not that it doesn't work (according to your question you tried `index.mustach` not `index.mustache` (notice the typo!). If it really doesn't find it ou must be disabling some auto-config or set something somewhere that stops the default from working.

Comment: Thank you. If I click the corresponding html in the controller, the corresponding html now appears. In the view resolver, there seems to be no problem now, but when deploying to Tomcat, the 404 error still appears. It is probably a Tomcat problem.

Comment: Why are you deploying to tomcat? YOu are creating a jar not a war so nothing will deploy on tomcat?

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm misunderstanding something. Executing in the application main method is a jar, so it works normally, but Tomcat is a war type, so there is a problem?

Comment: Your project delivers a jar not a war (judging from your build file).

Comment: Thanks, I have a clear understanding of the war jar concept and can use it in my projects. All issues have been resolved